# Laravel resolving Guzzle multiple times

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I have a system built using Laravel that is posting data to an external api. In order to be able to mock the HTTP requests in my tests, I'm resolving the Guzzle instance from the service container:

```
    $data = ['foo' => 'bar'];
    $httpClient = resolve('GuzzleHttp\Client');
    try {
        $response = $httpClient->post('example.com', ['form_params' => $data]);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        if ($e->hasResponse()) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
        }
    }
```

Since this is a HTTP request to an external api and I don't know how long it will take, I'm using a job that is dispatched to a queue, so it runs when possible.

However, I reached a point where the queue had 50 pending items, so I've decided to increase the number of workers (to 25) in order to process everything faster but I started to get:
`Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\Submit has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out`.

Each worker was configured to do only one attempt and without any time limit. No exceptions were logged in the laravel logs apart from the `MaxAttemptsExceededException` one.

Could it be related to the way I'm instantiating the Guzzle client? When we do `resolve('GuzzleHttp\Client')` is Laravel returning the same instance for all workers or is it a fresh instance for each worker?

Comment: "Each worker was configured to do only one attempt and without any time limit" what is you retry and timeout settings set to?

Comment: retry_after = 3600; timeout = 0

Comment: It depends on how you registered it. Could you add how you register the service?

Comment: I've only installed guzzle using composer and then the code above. I guess the resolving process is done by laravel service container, maybe using Reflection?